# "Partition Misaligned by 1024 bytes" on encrypted lvm

Tags: partitioning, encryption, gparted, lvm

Disk Utility is giving me the error "The partition is misaligned by 1024 bytes. This may result in very poor performance. Repartitioning is suggested" on a partition which holds an encrypted LVM.

I have looked at this question (and several like it)

- [File system is not clean (The partition is misaligned by 1024 bytes)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134023/file-system-is-not-clean-the-partition-is-misaligned-by-1024-bytes)

However there is an issue caused by the use of an encrypted partition. GParted, for example, cannot resize an encrypted volume or the partition which holds it.

Is there any way to resize the partition to align it properly? Neither Disk Utility nor GParted will let me do this.

EDIT: This still hasn't been solved so I can't award the bounty...

Comment: Please edit your question to include an outline of your partitioning scheme and also the model of your hard drive.

Comment: And also, *how* are you setting up LVM and encryption - a clean install, or...?

Comment: Most recently I pre-formatted the drive with GParted on a liveCD, aligning to MiB, and then used the created partitions to install the OS

Comment: So after Gparted, you booted up the Alternate CD, chose manual and set up LVM and encryption? Please include a screenshot of your partitions if possible. I'm not having this problem starting from the Alternate CD...

Comment: Yeah, I chose manual and select the 1st (200MiB) partition as `/boot/` and the other one as "physical volume for lvm partition"

Comment: With large drives, disk alignment occurs every 4K or 4096bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I had to remove the LVM and use standard, unencrypted partitions. The issue stopped and I've noticed a significant performance increase... Still not perfect though, and I'm sorry nobody could answer :(

Comment: I have this problem too, not matter what I do, or how many times I reformat, or even what distro I am using, be it Debian, Kali or Ubuntu, this error persists.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way to solve this is:

- backup your important files to another hard drive
- format the partition (or the whole hard drive) using an ubuntu live cd and gparted.

Some people complain of *very low speed* when they have this misalignment. **If you don't have slow speed** when reading/writing to the partition, I suggest you leave it as it is and **simply ignore the warning**. That is, until you find an opportunity (another hard drive, and time) to reformat the drive.

Comment: I've already tried reformatting with different partition sizes and have the same problem; as I mentioned in the OP I can't use gparted as it doesn't support LUKS encryption (that is to say I can remove the existing one but wouldn't be able to create it again)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with disk encryption, but you may be able to use dm-crypt instead of luks: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15774/encrypting-a-non-linux-partition-with-luks -- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions

Comment: also this post looks very promising: http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?pid=29127#p29127

Comment: I just wiped the hard drive and pre-formatted with GParted (aligning to MiB) and then installed on the new, aligned partitions. Still get this error :/

Comment: Then you didn't align it correctly: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw074KB-Disksdth-LX

Comment: Be sure to review the answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/30071/the-partition-is-misaligned-error-in-disk-utility-should-i-repartition/30939#30939 and links mentioned there. It essentially point to the link ppetraki posted.

Comment: Very interesting post, I believe this question is a duplicate then. @jackweirdy can you please check if Jamess' answer fixes your issue? If it doesn't, try to delete the MSDOS partition table, and use GPT instead (from gparted menu Device > Create partition table).

Comment: @mediageek, changing partition styles won't matter, there will always be some sort of offset. You can achieve proper alignment using any partitioning scheme but first you have to understand the fundamentals, understand what to look for, and execute correctly.

Comment: None of the posts mentioned so far have helped :/ Just for reference, these seem to be pointed towards Western Digital drives, mine is a Hitachi (Will post exact model number soon)